# Como alterar a resposta do WebHook no WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, webhook

Tenho um problema na REST_API do WooCommerce, no caso a resposta do endpoint *wp-json/wc/v2/orders*, nos produtos(line_items) não é retornado as *metadatas*(*metadatas* dos produtos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como na imagem acima, pode ser observado que os valores para as *metadatas*, estão vazios!

Solucionei essa questão utilizando *register_rest_field*, esse é o código da solução abaixo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução adiciona a **key** *products* na resposta da REST_API, dentro dessa array tem o id do produto junto com as *metadatas* que preciso!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que eu quero que essa alteração seja aplicada no WebHook, pensei que alterando o a resposta do endpoint da REST_API, também fosse alterar a resposta do WebHook. Porém esse script não surtiu efeitos no WebHook.

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando o filtro

`*woocommerce_rest_prepare_{$post_type}_object*!`

Essa foi a solução:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Evite usar imagens com código. Para responder copie o seu código e usa as ferramentas do campo resposta para colar ele aqui da forma correta.